# Page display issue

Tags: html, firefox

Exactly the div tag should be place in right hand side but this is placed in left hand side only in firefox.
My page looks fine in any other browser but in firefox the page looks differnet my code is

```
<div style="width: 400px; height: 280px; float:left; margin-left: 15px;margin-top: 3px">

    <div class="slider-wrap">
        <div id="main-photo-slider" class="csw">
            <div class="panelContainer">

                <div class="panel" title="Panel 1">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <img src="image/forslider/slider1.jpg" alt="" style="border-style: solid; height: 266px; width: 392px;"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel" title="Panel 2">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <img src="image/forslider/slider2.jpg" alt="" style="border-style: solid; height: 266px; width: 392px;"/>

                    </div>
                </div>      
                <div class="panel" title="Panel 3">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <img src="image/forslider/slider3.jpg" alt="" style="border-style: solid; height: 266px; width: 392px;"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel" title="Panel 4">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <img src="image/forslider/slider4.jpg" alt="" style="border-style: solid; height: 266px; width: 392px;"/>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel" title="Panel 5">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <img src="image/forslider/slider5.jpg" alt="" style="border-style: solid; height: 266px; width: 392px;"/>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel" title="Panel 6">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <img src="image/forslider/slider6.jpg" alt="" style="border-style: solid; height: 266px; width: 392px;"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the div tag must be placed in right hand side.

Comment: Make a working example of the bug and upload it somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change from `float:left;` to `float:right;` in the first div

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>align</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#right {
    text-align: left;
    width: 200px;
    position:absolute;
    right:1%;
    background-color: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="right">Some Text</div>    
</body>
</html>
```